# "do some talking" vs. "talk"

Tags: meaning

In a English classroom, each student has 2 minutes to talk about themselves like their hobbies, their hometown etc.

I am trying to invite one classmate to practice with me. Is it clear and natural to say it like this?

> Hi, Richard, let's do some talking to practice the new phrases we just learned.

I guess it is more natural than this one

> Hi, Richard, let's talk to practice ...

Is my understanding correct? If yes, "do some talking" and "talk" don't mean the same thing, what's the difference?

Comment: I don't think there's any difference in meaning at all, which is why "do some talking" doesn't sound idiomatic. If "talk" means exactly the same thing, then native speakers will prefer the more concise version.

Comment: I agree - shorten to "Hey, Richard! Let's practice the new phrases we learned.", or "Would you like to practice speaking (English)?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Do some talking", as part of an invitation to have a discussion, doesn't sound idiomatic at all, but your sentence doesn't sound natural with "talk" either.

In British English, a language teacher is most likely to refer to this as "speaking practice", for example:

> Hi Richard, let's *do some speaking practice with the new phrases we just learned*.

Or, you could just simply say:

> Hi, Richard, let's practice the new phrases we just learned.

Practising phrases *implies* talking, so there's really no need to say it at all.

As an aside, note that this kind of "practice" is spelled "practise" in British English.